# How do I programmatically remove passwords from excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, powershell

A few weeks ago, I had to remove password protection from excel files which were created by an application. I had no passwords. Can this task be done with powershell, using xml transformation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42860894/4961700

Comment: No, this solution does not need passwords at all!

Comment: Duplucate for **result** not method...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I want to share with you. The powershell script removes passwords and sheet protections from Excel files using powershell. No Excel application and no passwords are needed. The script is working only for .xlsx file types, not for .xls. If you have ideas for improvement, let me know. Thank you.

```
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function Remove-Excel-WriteProtection {
    <#
    // Removes all password and write protection from existing excel file
    // (workbook and worksheets). 
    // No password needed.
    // 
    // Input:   Path to Excel file (must newer xlsx format)
    // Output:  true if successfull
    #>
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$filePathExcel     
        )

        if( !(Test-Path -Path $filePathExcel) -or 
            !(Split-Path -Path $filePathExcel -Leaf).EndsWith('xlsx') ) {
            return $false
        }

        $fileItem      = Get-Item $filePathExcel
        $filePathZip   = $fileItem.DirectoryName + '\' + $fileItem.BaseName + '.zip'
        $filePathTemp  = $fileItem.DirectoryName + '\' + ([System.Guid]::NewGuid()).Guid 

        Rename-Item -Path $filePathExcel -NewName $filePathZip -Force
        Expand-Archive -Path $filePathZip -DestinationPath $filePathTemp -Force

        $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true

        $workbookCollection = (Get-ChildItem -Path $filePathTemp -Filter 'workbook.xml' -Recurse -Force)

        foreach( $workbook in $workbookCollection ) {

            [void]$xml.RemoveAll()
            [void]$xml.Load($workbook.FullName)

            if( $xml.workbook.fileSharing.readOnlyRecommended -or $xml.workbook.fileSharing.reservationPassword ) {

                if( $xml.workbook.fileSharing.readOnlyRecommended ) {
                    $xml.workbook.fileSharing.readOnlyRecommended = '0'
                }
                if( $xml.workbook.fileSharing.reservationPassword ) {
                    $xml.workbook.fileSharing.reservationPassword = ''
                }

                [void]$xml.Save($workbook.FullName)
            }
        }

        $worksheetCollection = (Get-ChildItem -Path $filePathTemp -Filter 'sheet*.xml' -Recurse -Force)

        foreach( $worksheet in $worksheetCollection ) {

            [void]$xml.RemoveAll()
            [void]$xml.Load($worksheet.FullName)

            if( $xml.worksheet.sheetProtection ) {
                [void]$xml.worksheet.RemoveChild($xml.worksheet.sheetProtection)
                [void]$xml.Save($worksheet.FullName)
            }
        }

        Remove-Item -Path $filePathZip -Force
        Compress-Archive -Path ($filePathTemp + '\*') -DestinationPath $filePathZip -Force -CompressionLevel Optimal
        Remove-Item -Path $filePathTemp -Recurse -Force
        Rename-Item -Path $filePathZip -NewName $filePathExcel -Force

        return $true
    }

    # Remove all passwords for test.xlsx

    $result = Remove-Excel-WriteProtection -filePathExcel 'C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\test.xlsx'
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work in modern Excel versions.

Comment: You're wrong. This script is working especially with the new Excel file formats. Do you have tested it before downvoting??? If yes, pls send me the respective Excel file, I'll check.